# How to see MySQL queries in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to see which MySQL queries are fired from ActiveRecord in the rails console?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved through redirecting rails log to standard output.

Write these in your console prompt:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.clear_reloadable_connections!
```

Furthermore, you can put these lines in ~/.irbrc file, so that each time you don't need to manually write these 2 lines:

```
require 'rubygems'

if ENV.include?('RAILS_ENV') && ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == 'development'
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.clear_reloadable_connections!
end
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I just tried adding this to the `.irbrc` file for an old Rails 2.3 project. Says ActiveRecord isn't loaded yet when I run script/console. Is there some load hack I need to do first?

Comment: just add `require 'active_record'` below `require 'rubygems'`

Comment: Just the first one `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 3+ you can use ActiveRecord::Relation’s [`to_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-to_sql) method:

```
User.where(:id => 3).to_sql
#=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE \"users\".\"id\" = 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it for each project is inspired by http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#what-is-the-logger-questionmark:

You can specify an alternative logger in your environment.rb or any environment file:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new("log/active_record.log") #This outputs the mysql queries to a file named active_record.log under your project's log folder.
```

Of course, you need to restart your server to make things work.